# Is there a way to make alt+F4 always quit an application?

Tags: windows

I have some games and other applications that think it's good design to disable the alt+F4 combination. I have to either move through several menus to quit to desktop, or alt+tab out and kill the process in the task manager. This is incredibly annoying. Is there a registry setting or some other way to have alt+f4 always force close an application without it being overridden by whatever application is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super F4 has helped me out, and several years later still kills everything. https://stefansundin.github.io/superf4/

Simply install it, and the combination ctrl+alt+F4 will kill the foreground application instantly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: At the very least you should descibe *how* to use the software to solve the problem as asked in the question. [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers). How does this tool achieve what is asked? How do you use it? How do you set it up?

Answer (score 1):

Check out an app named named AutoHotKey. I'm sure there's a way using that to send a pskill command (or any other type of "kill this process" command) to the active window using it. It's basically a way to setup and use custom hotkeys in Windows. It may not let you use ALT+F4, but you would easily be able to setup any other hotkey you want to do the same function.